# Adding new column with conditional values using ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with more than 400.000 observations and I'm trying to add a column to it which its values depend on another column and sometimes multiple ones.

Here is a simpler example of what I'm trying to do :

```
# Creating a data frame 

M <- data.frame(c("A","B","C"),c(5,100,60))

names(M) <- c("Letter","Number")

#adding a column 

M$Size <- NA

# if Number <= 50 Size is small, 
# if Number is between 50 and 70, Size is Medium
# if Number is Bigger than 70, Size is Big

ifelse (M$Number <=50, M$Size <-"Small",
        ifelse(M$Number <= 70,
        M$Size <- "Medium",
        M$Size <- "Big"
        ))
```

When I run the Code, the output I get is :

```
[1] "Small"  "Big"    "Medium"
```

But the "Size" column in M is always the last condition in the ifelse function :

```
> print (M)
  Letter Number Size
1      A      5  Big
2      B    100  Big
3      C     60  Big
```

**The Result that I want :**

```
> print (M)
  Letter Number Size
1      A      5  Small
2      B    100  Big
3      C     60  Medium
```

I can solve the problem by subsetting  each condition`subset` and using `rbind` to get the result I want but the code will be very long and since the original data frame I'm working on is big, it'll take more time to run. So I'm wondering how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: cut(M[, 2], c(-Inf, 50,70, Inf), c("Small", "Medium", "Big"))

Answer (score 13):

This will help you out -

```
# Creating a data frame 

M <- data.frame(c("A","B","C"),c(5,100,60))

names(M) <- c("Letter","Number")

#adding a column 


# if Number <= 50 Size is small, 
# if Number is between 50 and 70, Size is Medium
# if Number is Bigger than 70, Size is Big

# M$Size[M$Number <= 50] <- "Small"
# Edit: No need to subset "Small"
M$Size <- "Small"
M$Size[M$Number >50 & M$Number<70] <- "Medium"
M$Size[M$Number > 70] <- "Big"

#      Letter Number   Size
# 1      A      5      Small
# 2      B    100      Big
# 3      C     60      Medium
```

See this on [R-Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=C06G1K5R)

Comment: This is better than using `ifelse`. Have an upvote. However, you don't need the subsetting in the first step if there are no `NA` values. Just do `M$Size <- "Small"`.

Comment: @Roland Yes you are right, I oversaw that. Will edit

Answer (score 10):

Use `cut`:

```
M$Size <- cut(M$Number, breaks = c(-Inf, 50, 70, Inf), 
                        labels = c("small", "medium", "large"))
#   etter Number   Size
#1      A      5  small
#2      B    100  large
#3      C     60 medium
```

Answer (score 6):

Same idea but assign it like this instead. No package needed.

```
M$Size <- ifelse(M$Number <= 50, 'Small', ifelse(M$Number <= 70, 'Medium', 'Big'))
```

Result:

```
  Letter Number   Size
1      A      5  Small
2      B    100    Big
3      C     60 Medium
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
df <- data.frame(c("A","B","C"),c(5,100,60))
names(df) <- c("Letter","Number")

df$Size = with(df,
               ifelse(Number <= 50, 'Small',
                     ifelse(Number > 50 & Number < 70, 'Medium',
                           ifelse(Number > 70, 'Big', 'NA'))))
```