# Creating a new column in a data.frame with an "if else" structure

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I would like to create a new column in a dataframe where the cells of the dataframe would depend on a condition. Here is some reproducible code :

```
a <- c("Boy","Girl","Dog","Cat")
b <- c("1","2","3","4")
df <- data.frame(a,b)

if(df$a=="Boy"|df$b=="Girl"){

  df$Type <- "Human"
}
else(
  df$Type <- "Animal"
)
# This is what I would like to achieve :
df$Type <- c("Human","Human","Animal","Animal")
```

But when executing the condition, this is the error message I get :

```
Warning message:
In if (df$a == "Boy" | df$b == "Girl") { :
  condition has a length > 1 only the first element is used
```

Comment: use `df$a %in% c("Boy", "Girl")` instead of `|`

Comment: Something more like `df$Type  <- ifelse(df$a %in% c("Boy", "Girl"), "Human","Animal")`

Comment: `df$Type <- ifelse(df$a == "Boy" | df$b == "Girl", "Human", "Animal")`. But note that you are checking the `b` column for `"Girl"` which does not match your data.

Comment: When typing "if(df$a %in% c("Boy", "Girl")){
  
  df$Type <- "Human"
}"  I still get Warning message:
In if (df$a %in% c("Boy", "Girl")) { :
  condition has a length > 1

Comment: @Axeman yes sorry for the typo I meant df$a == "Girl

Comment: Thanks Axeman, it works !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding new column with conditional values using ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321020/adding-new-column-with-conditional-values-using-ifelse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dplyr::case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(type = case_when(
    a %in% c("Boy", "Girl") ~ "Human",
    TRUE ~ "Animal"
  )
)
```

Comment: Since there's only one condition being tested, you could just use base `ifelse`; no need for `dplyr::case_when`