# How to flag/count missing values in RStudio on a row by row basis?

Tags: r, dataframe

Taking the airquality dataset from the MASS library as an example:

```
> head(airquality)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

I want to create three columns:

`Missing_Ozone`, `Missing_Total` and `Missing_Percent`, such that:

`Missing_Ozone = 1` if there is a missing value in the Ozone column in the current row.

`Missing_total` = total count of missing values in the current row

`Missing_Percent` = percentage of missing values in a row.

So for example, in row 1:

`Missing_Ozone = 0`, `Missing_total = 0`, `Missing_percent = 0`

In row 5:

`Missing_Ozone = 1`, `Missing_total = 2`, `Missing percent = 100*(2/6)`

In row 6:

`Missing_Ozone = 0`, `Missing_total = 1`, `Missing percent = 100*(1/6)`

I tried two approaches, without any luck:

The first was to iterate over each row and use an if statement:

```
library(MASS)
df_test = airquality

df_test$Missing_Ozone <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(df_test)){
  if (is.na(df_test$Ozone)) {
    df_test$Missing_Ozone <- 1
  } 
}
```

The second was to just use the if-statement inside that for-loop.

Neither work, and I just get:

```
> df_test
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day Missing_Ozone
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1             0
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2             0
3      12     149 12.6   74     5   3             0
4      18     313 11.5   62     5   4             0
5      NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5             0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Also, does this type of data manipulation have a certain name? I found it hard to search online for a guide that goes through this type of data manipulation.

Comment: In your for loop you have a small, but significant bug: `df_test$Missing_Ozone[i] <- 1`, otherwise you’re assigning 1 to the whole column.

Comment: What you would want to look for is something along the lines of `create column, conditional, another column`. 
[This is one approach via ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37321200/9406040)

Comment: @Roman - Thank you! I also needed to have `is.na(df_test$Ozone[i])` instead of `is.na(df_test$Ozone)` - it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tidyverse approach:

```
library(dplyr)
airquality <- datasets::airquality
cols <- ncol(airquality)

airquality <- airquality %>%
    mutate(
        Missing_Ozone = as.numeric(is.na(Ozone)),
        Missing_Total = rowSums(is.na(.)),
        Missing_Percent = Missing_Total/cols
    )
```

```
> head(airquality)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day Missing_Ozone Missing_Total Missing_Percent
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1             0             0       0.0000000
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2             0             0       0.0000000
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3             0             0       0.0000000
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4             0             0       0.0000000
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5             1             2       0.3333333
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6             0             1       0.1666667
```

### Base R approach:

```
cols <- ncol(airquality)
airquality$Missing_Ozone <- as.numeric(is.na(airquality$Ozone))
airquality$Missing_Total <- rowSums(is.na(airquality))
airquality$Missing_Percent <- airquality$Missing_Total/cols
```

```
> head(airquality)
>   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day Missing_Ozone Missing_Total Missing_Percent
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1             0             0       0.0000000
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2             0             0       0.0000000
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3             0             0       0.0000000
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4             0             0       0.0000000
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5             1             2       0.3333333
6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6             0             1       0.1666667
```

### edit: A note on performance

I would advise in general against usage of `rowwise` operations outside of very specific use cases. It will slow you down heavily as your data set scales. The execution time tends to grow linearly with your data, which is really, really bad. A little benchmark with a data set size of `6,426` rows instead of `153`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

airquality <- datasets::airquality

# Rowwise
approachA <- function(data) {
    result <- data %>%
        mutate(Missing_Ozone = as.integer(is.na(Ozone))) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(Missing_Total = sum(is.na((c_across(-Missing_Ozone))))) %>%
        mutate(Missing_Percent = Missing_Total/ncol(data)) %>%
        ungroup()
    return(result)
}

# Tidy
approachB <- function(data) {
    cols <- ncol(data)
    result <- data %>%
        mutate(
            Missing_Ozone = as.numeric(is.na(Ozone)),
            Missing_Total = rowSums(is.na(.)),
            Missing_Percent = Missing_Total/cols
        )
    return(result)
}

# Base R
approachC <- function(data) {
    cols <- ncol(data)
    data$Missing_Ozone <- as.numeric(is.na(data$Ozone))
    data$Missing_Total <- rowSums(is.na(data))
    data$Missing_Percent <- data$Missing_Total/cols
    return(data)
}
```

**Result with data x 42:** `rowwise()` has led to some orders of magnitude worse performance over both proposed approaches.

```
> test_data <- do.call("rbind", replicate(42, airquality, simplify = FALSE))
> set.seed(42)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(approachA(test_data), approachB(test_data), approachC(test_data))
Unit: microseconds
                 expr        min          lq        mean      median          uq        max neval cld
 approachA(test_data) 243340.904 251838.3590 259083.8089 256546.9015 260567.8945 405326.615   100   b
 approachB(test_data)    577.977    624.0610    723.8304    741.0955    770.3695   2382.756   100  a 
 approachC(test_data)    102.377    107.9735    139.5595    119.6175    129.4165   2074.231   100  a
```

**Result with data x 420:** Execution time of `rowwise` approach has grown 10x.

```
test_data <- do.call("rbind", replicate(420, airquality, simplify = FALSE))
> set.seed(42)
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(approachA(test_data), approachB(test_data), approachC(test_data))
Unit: microseconds
                 expr         min         lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
 approachA(test_data) 2519480.258 2620528.08 2671419.663 2672263.417 2707896.209 2907659.730   100   b
 approachB(test_data)    1266.818    1488.71    1909.167    1576.327    1678.725   21011.147   100  a 
 approachC(test_data)     808.684     881.09    1220.151    1000.277    1067.907    8218.655   100  a
```

Comment: Thanks for the microbenchmark. Please change `Missing_Total/ncol(airquality)` to `Missing_Total/ncol(data)` as that is the correct way to reference the column number of the `data`. No need to re-run the code as `rowwise` approach is for sure the slowest.

Comment: My earlier comments on `rowSums` is not correct. But the point is, if the users wants to only count the total missing values in a certain columns, not in all columns, then you need some extra work for that `rowSums` statement.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `dplyr` package. `rowwise` and `c_cross` allow us to do calculation by each row.

```
library(dplyr)

dat <- airquality %>%
  mutate(Missing_Ozone = as.integer(is.na(Ozone))) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Missing_Total = sum(is.na((c_across(-Missing_Ozone))))) %>%
  mutate(Missing_Percent = Missing_Total/ncol(airquality)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat
# # A tibble: 153 x 9
#    Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day Missing_Ozone Missing_Total Missing_Percent
#    <int>   <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>         <int>         <int>           <dbl>
#  1    41     190   7.4    67     5     1             0             0           0    
#  2    36     118   8      72     5     2             0             0           0    
#  3    12     149  12.6    74     5     3             0             0           0    
#  4    18     313  11.5    62     5     4             0             0           0    
#  5    NA      NA  14.3    56     5     5             1             2           0.333
#  6    28      NA  14.9    66     5     6             0             1           0.167
#  7    23     299   8.6    65     5     7             0             0           0    
#  8    19      99  13.8    59     5     8             0             0           0    
#  9     8      19  20.1    61     5     9             0             0           0    
# 10    NA     194   8.6    69     5    10             1             1           0.167
# # ... with 143 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks, the other commenters suggestion worked but I am interested in getting more familiar with dplyr, so this helps a lot.

Comment: that's a really, really inefficient approach, @www

Comment: @Roman Thanks for your comments. Yes, `rowwise` is slow. But for a data frame with about a hundred rows, I would say the efficiency is tolerable.

Comment: @Roman In addition to efficiency, sometimes the readability is also a consideration. In this example, it is clear that the code conduct a rowwise operation. It is plus if sometimes I need to communicate with others.